# Zend PSR7 does not work on Lumen?

Tags: php, zend-framework, lumen, psr-7

Zend PSR7 does not seem to work on Lumen:

```
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Zend\Diactoros\Response;

// PSR 7
$app->bind('Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface', function ($app) {
    return (new Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\DiactorosFactory)->createRequest($app->make('request'));
});

// PSR 7.
$app->get('hello/{name}', function (ServerRequestInterface $request) {

    // Interact with the PSR-7 request
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');

    // var_dump($request->getHeaders());
    var_dump($name); // get NULL instead of 'world'

    // Interact with the PSR-7 response
    $response = new Response();
    $response->getBody()->write('Hello, ' . $name);

    return $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
});
```

First 'error':

```
var_dump($name); // get NULL instead of 'world'
```

Second ERROR:

```
UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 395:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.
in Response.php line 395
at Response->setContent(object(Response)) in Response.php line 54
at Response->setContent(object(Response)) in Response.php line 198
at Response->__construct(object(Response)) in Application.php line 1454
at Application->prepareResponse(object(Response)) in Application.php line 1314
at Application->callActionOnArrayBasedRoute(array('1', array(object(Closure)), array('name' => 'world'))) in Application.php line 1288
at Application->handleFoundRoute(array('1', array(object(Closure)), array('name' => 'world'))) in Application.php line 1262
at Application->handleDispatcherResponse(array('1', array(object(Closure)), array('name' => 'world'))) in Application.php line 1212
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\{closure}() in Application.php line 1442
at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure)) in Application.php line 1213
at Application->dispatch(object(Request)) in Application.php line 1153
at Application->run(object(Request)) in index.php line 28
```

Any ideas why?

Slim3 seems to be easier and more straight forward!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [my PSR HTTP library](https://github.com/terrylinooo/psr-http):

```
$response = new \Shieldon\Psr7\Response();
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use this

`use Laminas\Diactoros\Response as Psr7Response;`

As Zend has been moved to Laminas, you can read more [here](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-diactoros/v2/custom-responses/).

Comment: Please explain your answer more inside your answer, as links will become non-functional over time.